# Cross compiling ROS Barebones on ARM for QNX

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a toolchain installed for QNX 7 and I followed the instructions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/191070/compile-roscore-for-arm-board/) to cross compile it. The environment variables are all set to the QNX libraries which are set by a toolchain. This is on Ubuntu 16.04 for ROS Kinetic barebones install.

When I run this command from my catkin_workspace I get the following error,

```
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests
/opt/qnx/install/target/qnx7/armle-v7/usr/bin/python: 1: /opt/qnx/install/target/qnx7/armle-v7/usr/bin/python: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
CMake Error at cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/opt/qnx/install/target/qnx7/armle-v7/usr/bin/python
  "/opt/qnx/install/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/qnx/install/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/opt/qnx/install/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 2
```

I need to use only the message publisher/subscriber of ros for my application.

Any inputs or ideas would be hghly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264398/cross-compiling-ros-barebones-on-arm-for-qnx/) by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is

```
opt/qnx/install/target/qnx7/armle-v7/usr/bin/python
```

this the path to your python? And if you run the code an your dev(x64) machine then this should show to your local python not the arm python interpreter.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on 2017-06-22**:
Thank you! That fixed the issue